# How to extract short sequence based on step size?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, extract, biopython, fasta

The code below extract short sequence in every sequence with the window size 100. The window will shift by step size one and extract the sequence. I would like to extract the short sequence with every step size 50. Can anyone help me?

```
 from Bio import SeqIO

 with open("B.fasta","w") as f:
         for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("A.fasta", "fasta"):
             for i in range(len(seq_record.seq) - 99) :
                f.write(str(">"+seq_record.id) + "\n")
                f.write(str(seq_record.seq[i:i+100]) + "\n")
```

Example of fasta file:

```
>hg17_ct_ER_ER_142
CTAAAAAAGTAAAAAAGAAAAAAAGAGAAAGAAAGAATATAGAAGCAACAAGTGTAGATTTACATTCTATTAGACAGTGACCCATTAGACCCGGACAAGGGG
```

Example output:

```
>hg17_ct_ER_ER_142
CTAAAAAAGTAAAAAAGAAAAAAAGAGAAAGAAAGAATATAGAAGCAACAAGTGTAGATTTACATTCTATTAGACAGTGACCCATTAGACCCGGACAAGG
>hg17_ct_ER_ER_142
TAAAAAAGTAAAAAAGAAAAAAAGAGAAAGAAAGAATATAGAAGCAACAAGTGTAGATTTACATTCTATTAGACAGTGACCCATTAGACCCGGACAAGGG
>hg17_ct_ER_ER_142
AAAAAAGTAAAAAAGAAAAAAAGAGAAAGAAAGAATATAGAAGCAACAAGTGTAGATTTACATTCTATTAGACAGTGACCCATTAGACCCGGACAAGGGG
```

Expected output:

```
>hg17_ct_ER_ER_142
CTAAAAAAGTAAAAAAGAAAAAAAGAGAAAGAAAGAATATAGAAGCAACA
>hg17_ct_ER_ER_142
AGTGTAGATTTACATTCTATTAGACAGTGACCCATTAGACCCGGACAAGG
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract short sequence using window with specific step size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30797796/how-to-extract-short-sequence-using-window-with-specific-step-size)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the step size option to the range function:

```
for i in range(0, len(seq_record.seq) - 99, 50) :
```